# finding regression coefficients and deviation with autocorrellated outlaws

Tags: r, regression, time-series, autocorrelation, outliers

I try to make regression analyses to vector of average month C02 concentration in the air.

```
data = c(349.94,    343.98, 337.96, 339.09, 342.85, 345.66, 348.97,351.34, 352.13,  352.74, 353.12, 353.32, 351.45, 345.76, 340.4,  339.93, 344.37, 347.96, 349.73, 351.03, 352.39, 353.51, 354.05, 354.27, 352.93, 348.14, 341.97, 341.82, 346.41, 350.37, 352.65, 354.42, 355.66, 356.66, 357.48, 357.48, 355.49, 350.24, 344.82, 345.46, 350.78, 354.39, 356.02, 357.9,  359.49, 360.34, 359.86, 359.38, 358.04, 351.51, 345.67, 346.63, 350.67, 355.63, 359.78, 360.17, 359.8,  360.7,  360.92, 360.47, 357.67, 351.36, 346.54, 346.78, 351.25, 355.83, 358.55, 360.7,  361.51, 361.59, 361.85, 361.7,  360.14, 354.29, 348,    348.63, 353.14, 357.22, 361.26, 362.82, 362.82, 363.37, 363.03, 362.95, 361.17, 353.67, 347.15, 347.85, 351.94, 356.64, 360.19, 361.37, 361.77, 362.73, 363.42, 363.47, 360.61, 354.12, 348.48, 349.08, 353.1,  357.47, 360.51, 362.83, 364.4,  364.96, 364.72, 364.24, 362.25, 356.89, 350.71, 350.57, 355.65, 360.57, 363.12, 364.38, 365.6,  366.04, 365.62, 365.53, 363.95, 357.72, 352.34, 353.06, 357.61, 362.63, 365.36, 366.16, 366.74, 367.32, 367.75, 368.54, 367.66, 362.33, 355.7,  354.89, 359.34, 363.24, 366.13, 368.18, 368.71, 368.3,  368.49, 369.02, 367.08, 360.6,  355.27, 356.08, 360.9,  364.58, 367.38, 369.41, 370.35, 370.41, 370.56, 371.29, 369.54, 363.33, 358.34, 359.79, 364.17, 368.67, 371.62, 372.91, 373.65, 374.03, 374.36, 374.49, 371.53, 364.88, 359.34, 360.33, 364.48, 369.29, 372.5,  373.57, 374.46, 375.08, 375.4,  375.79, 373.29, 366.55, 361.21, 361.89, 366.66, 370.79, 373.27, 375.29, 376.13, 376.32, 377.13, 377.55, 374.53, 367.18, 361.88, 362.93, 368.27, 372.96, 375.27, 376.97, 377.93, 378.44, 378.67, 378.43, 376.29, 370.26, 364.51, 365.38, 370.63, 374.29, 376.5,  379.13, 381.09, 381.43, 381.44, 382.02, 379.64, 372.58, 367.8,  368.57, 373.03, 377.33, 380.31, 381.95, 382.37, 382.52, 383.08, 383.7,  381.61, 375.22, 368.7,  368.73, 373.42, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 385.67, 385.58, 383.41, 377.31, 371.35, 371.7,  376.31, 381.83, 384.61, 384.97, 385.76, 386.9,  387.6,  388.44, 386.93, 379.7,  373.75, 374.68, 379.25, 383.87, 387.06, 388.75, 389.12, 389.61, 389.8,  389.44, 387.6,  380.38, 373.23, 374.52, 380.33, 385.09, 388.84, 390.32, 391.08, 392.29, 392.68, 392.41, 389.21, 382.36, 377.19, 377.39, 382.19, 387.06, 390.72, 392.52, 392.24, 392.4,  393.73, 393.85, 391.27, 384.28, 377.73, 378.26, 382.78, 387.56, 391.37, 393.14, 393.54, 394.16, 395.22, 395.62, 392.59, 386.09, 380.95, 382.46, 387.05, 391.49, 394.61, 396.11, 396.91, 397.6,  398.07, 397.9,  394.99, 388.51, 381.66, 382.09, 388.15, 393.72, 396.88, 398.18, 398.56, 399.29, 400.02, 400.05, 396.94, 388.66, 383.22, 385.23, 390.61, 395.77, 399.01, 400.45, 401.03, 401.31, 402.04, 402.95, 401.3,  394.63, 388.35, 388.64, 393.83, 398.9,  402.04, 403.03, 403.78, 404.6,  404.74, 404.92, 402.28, 394.79, 389.28, 389.86, 394.57, 399.52, 403.59, 404.99, 406.39, 407.47, 406.93, 406.61, 403.59, 396.38, 391.18, 392.47, 397.08, 402.69, 406.22, 407.55, 408.43, 409.09, 409.63, 409.01, 405.41, 399.01, 393.8,  395.37, 400.69, 405.7,  409.24, 411.29, 412.33, 413.38, 413.62, 413.26, 410.16, 402.56, 396.9,  397.69, 402.83, 407.79, 410.79)
x =seq(1:391)
```

Concentration of CO2 in the air depends of season. So if I try to  find regression coefficients A and B with use of least squares,

```
y=Bx + A +e
```

vector e of outliers will have autocorreleation . How should I find regression coefficients and coefficients errors?

Comment: vecto x consists of integer sequence number from 1 to 391

Comment: I suggest making a scatterplot of the data, it does not appear to be CO2 levels over time.